# How can I do a batch conversion of HTML entities to Hanzi?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, text, html, unicode

I have a huge .txt file which contains lots of HTML entities representing Unicode characters, like this:

```
&#21696;&#29282;&#23665;
```

In Pinyin, this would read "Ai Lao Shan" or "Ai1 Lao2 Shan1", to be more precise.
I need a tool or command line or Pages/Numbers macro, whatever, which replaces all strings like `&#....;` in said file into proper Hanzi, which in this case would be:

```
哀牢山
```

Any suggestions for a tool or script or program that runs on macOS?

Comment: Have you looked at online converters like.  https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-html-entities-to-utf8

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be about Apple products or their use.

Comment: Thanks @jaume I’ve made a small edit specifying  macOS. Let’s see if this is on topic, [or a duplicate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81663/) or needs to be migrated to another OS site.

Comment: Thanks @TomGewecke, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

You can install [recode](http://www.gnu.org/software/recode/) via the Terminal with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install recode
```

and then use it to convert HTML to Unicode, like this:

```
echo '&#21696;&#29282;&#23665;' | recode html..utf8
```

This produces

> 哀牢山

<sub>(inspired by @creving's [answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5929519/4751173))</sub>